# Some problem using snap

Tags: 17.04, snap

I get this message every time using a snap command:

```
2017/06/17 16:54:53.238356 main.go:136: PANIC argument "ack"'s "forutsetningsfil>" should have <>s
panic: argument "ack"'s "forutsetningsfil>" should have <>s [recovered]
    panic: argument "ack"'s "forutsetningsfil>" should have <>s

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x55e1d83e20c0, 0xc420164e60)
    /usr/lib/go-1.7/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1a5
main.main.func1()
    /build/snapd-jGajdd/snapd-2.25+17.04/_build/src/github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snap/main.go:282 +0x82
panic(0x55e1d83e20c0, 0xc420164e60)
    /usr/lib/go-1.7/src/runtime/panic.go:458 +0x247
github.com/snapcore/snapd/logger.Panicf(0x55e1d80fffc7, 0x20, 0xc4201399e8, 0x2, 0x2)
    /build/snapd-jGajdd/snapd-2.25+17.04/_build/src/github.com/snapcore/snapd/logger/logger.go:72 +0x17a
main.lintArg(0x55e1d80efb9f, 0x3, 0xc42000d980, 0x11, 0xc4200be560, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0)
    /build/snapd-jGajdd/snapd-2.25+17.04/_build/src/github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snap/main.go:136 +0x1ad
main.Parser(0xc420139d40)
    /build/snapd-jGajdd/snapd-2.25+17.04/_build/src/github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snap/main.go:203 +0x8e9
main.run(0xc400000000, 0x55e1d8485d18)
    /build/snapd-jGajdd/snapd-2.25+17.04/_build/src/github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snap/main.go:302 +0x36
main.main()
    /build/snapd-jGajdd/snapd-2.25+17.04/_build/src/github.com/snapcore/snapd/cmd/snap/main.go:287 +0x197
```

Its on a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug in two translation files in 17.10 (and possibly others), nb and hr. There's also a bug in snapd that turns what should be an innocuous warning into a full on panic. We're fixing these (and I hope to get them into 2.29, but certainly 2.30), but meanwhile removing or renaming the appropriate `snappy.mo` should be enough to unblock you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Gustavo to help me fix it at
https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snap-not-working-in-terminal-on-ubuntu-17-10/2593/7

To get snap working properly you have to past this in the terminal prior to using snap commands:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Guess they will fix it soon :-).

Answer (score 0):

This is being caused by a broken translation file.

Try running with:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
snap --version
```

We'll review the logic so that it's both fixed and so it doesn't panic in those cases.